# Searching for an instance name

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I played WoW a few years ago (I think Wotlk or Cata was the newest expansion back then) and now I came back. I cant remember the name of an instance which was great. I cant remember which level I was when I played it but it could've been between 15 and 30. All I really know is that the last boss was located on a ship, and you first had to fight pirates to get to that ship, and the ship was in a kind of cave.

I ask this here because I already searched that new dungeon book, but I cant find the instance anywhere and I currently don't have enough time to play each instance to find out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instance you are looking for is The Deadmines.

This instance is for players between levels 15 and 21 for normal mode and level 85 for heroic mode. It is located in the southern part of the Westfall.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I just watched a video, and it...changed a bit. Now I know the name, but I still cant find it in the dungeon book/guide which you have in game. Either I'm stupid or its really not there.

Comment: I can't verify now but the instance was modified during Cataclysm so it may be in the Cataclysm part of dungeons.

Comment: Never thought of that, I'll check that as soon as possible

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [The Deadmines](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=1581/the-deadmines).

It is also worth mentioning that a revamped heroic version of the instance has been added with the Cataclysm expansion (see [here](http://www.wowpedia.org/World_of_Warcraft:_Cataclysm))